# Put TextView inside the View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, textview

I'm trying this SnowFall project. http://code.google.com/p/android-30days-apps/source/browse/trunk/08day/src/com/bakhtiyor/android/snowfall/SnowFall.java?r=27

And I need to put TextView inside View class(class SnowFallView extends View, line 42), how can I do it.

Can I instantiate TextView and add it like this?

```
 package in.isuru.animate;



 public class SnowFall extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SnowFallView snowFallView = new SnowFallView(this);
            setContentView(snowFallView);
            snowFallView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_image));

    }

    private class SnowFallView extends View {
            private int snow_flake_count = 5;
            private final List<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
            private int[][] coords;
            private final Drawable snow_flake;
            private TextView countDownView;

            public SnowFallView(Context context) {
                    super(context);
                    setFocusable(true);
                    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                    snow_flake = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.snow_flake);
                    snow_flake.setBounds(0, 0, snow_flake.getIntrinsicWidth(), snow_flake
                            .getIntrinsicHeight());

                    countDownView = new TextView(context);
                    countDownView.setText("It's working");
                    addContentView(countDownView, null);

                    //LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    //getWindow().addContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.text_layout, null), new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    //ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldw, int oldh) {
                    super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldw, oldh);
                    Random random = new Random();
                    Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

                    snow_flake_count = Math.max(width, height) / 20;
                    coords = new int[snow_flake_count][];
                    drawables.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < snow_flake_count; i++) {
                            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, height / 10
                                    - random.nextInt(height / 5), 0, height + 30);
                            animation.setDuration(10 * height + random.nextInt(5 * height));
                            animation.setRepeatCount(-1);
                            animation.initialize(10, 10, 10, 10);
                            animation.setInterpolator(interpolator);

                            coords[i] = new int[] { random.nextInt(width - 30), -30 };

                            drawables.add(new AnimateDrawable(snow_flake, animation));
                            animation.setStartOffset(random.nextInt(20 * height));
                            animation.startNow();
                    }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < snow_flake_count; i++) {
                            Drawable drawable = drawables.get(i);
                            canvas.save();
                            canvas.translate(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]);
                            drawable.draw(canvas);
                            canvas.restore();
                    }
                    invalidate();
            }

    } 
}
```

But when I do this I get an error.

06-04 00:22:22.364: E/AndroidRuntime(359): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.isuru.animate/in.isuru.animate.SnowFall}: java.lang.NullPointerException

PS. All imports done.

Comment: @Isuru : **I need to put TextView inside View class** You cannot put a `TextView` (or any type of `View`) inside another `View` only into a `ViewGroup`. The 'content' of your SnowFall `Activity` (as you mention) is a `SnowFallView` which extends `View`. It simply can't be done.

Comment: Ok, can I change view into view group, will it give errors to existing animation?

Comment: There is no solution for my problem, but thanks everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a `TextView` at run-time like that.  This assumes that `MyClass` subclasses `android.content.Context`.  I'm not sure what layout you are asking about in the second part of the question. You already have the container layout (linearLayout).

Answer (score 0):

```
countDownView = new TextView(context);
countDownView.setText("It's working");
addContentView(countDownView, null);
```

I think that your problem lays here:

```
addContentView(countDownView, null);
```

you should use

```
addView(countDownView)
```

instead of `addContentView`

Comment: Then I get an error called The method addView(TextView) is undefined for the type SnowFall.SnowFallView

Comment: yes your right. that`s because SnowFallView inherits from View instead of ViewGroup. addContentView is a method of the Window class. It needs valid layout params instead of null

Comment: try extending ViewGroup instead of View, and ovveride onLayout in order to give every child a position inside the ViewGroup

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is 100% correct but you need to do something like this...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    SnowFallView snowFallView = new SnowFallView(this);
    TextView txt1 = new TextView(this);
    linearLayout.addView(snowFallView);
    linearLayout.addView(txt1);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
    snowFallView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_image));
}
```

Also remove these lines from the `SnowFallView` class.

```
countDownView = new TextView(context);
countDownView.setText("It's working");
addContentView(countDownView, null);
```

Comment: How do I add test? I tried txt1.setText("Testing"); And it didn't show. TextView does not show.

Comment: It's possible the `SnowFallView` is taking up the full screen and there's no room for the `TextView`. Try changing the order of `addView(...)` so you add `txt1` first. You may need to adjust the size (bounds) of the `snow_flake` drawable to reduce the height.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, when I change the order it shows, like this.  http://i.imgur.com/uWuqO.jpg but I need to add the view top the the other view. How can I do that?

Comment: @Isuru : When you say **top** do you mean you want the `SnowFallView` at the top of the screen and the `TextView` below (opposite to the image you show)? Or do you mean the `TextView` overlaying the `SnowFallView`? You can do that by using a `FrameLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` and adding the `TextView` last. `FrameLayout` will 'layer' the views that are added to it. You will need to set vertical `padding` on the `TextView` to position it correctly though.